# Regex in Java which matches everything except a certain substring

Tags: java, regex

I'm looking for a regular expression which matches as much as possible without a certain substring. For example in "19weojustartspdfoj0u23stop308rstop23ij" I want to match with a expression like "start([^stop]*)" the substring "spdfoj0u23". The same expression should match "q039sdfkjfds" in "12ejipstartq039sdfkjfds" (here we have no stop, therefore we get everyting after "start".

Comment: This `start([^stop]*)` you tried would be [`start((?:(?!stop).)*)`](https://regex101.com/r/SlnQ4b/1) and known as [tempered greedy token](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed) (at least at *rexegg.com*). Pretty sure, this question is a dupe.

Answer (score 4):

You can use lookaround assertions to mark the beginning and end of the match. Making `.*` lazy, the first possible opportunity to end the match will be taken:

```
(?<=start).*?(?=stop|$)
```

The `$` matches with the end-of-input, which will occur when there is no `stop` following.